# Using fontello fonts in native iOS7 app

Tags: ios, fonts, nsattributedstring

How would I go about taking a character from here: http://fontello.com/ and using it in a native iOS 7 application for use in UILabels or UITextViews?

Is this an appropirate use for NSAttributedString?

Anyone have any examples of doing this type of work?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fine, with or without `NSAttributedString`. You can apply `NSFontNameAttribute` to certain ranges, or you can just assign the `font` property on the `UILabel`. A custom font is no different than any other kind of font (sort of… more in a moment).

So the basics. Create your font file. The piece you care about is the TTF (True Type Font). Copy it into your app, and make sure it's being copied in during the "Copy" phase. (It'll do that automatically if you just drop it into the app and add it to a target.)

Add it to your Info pane for your target. It's the "Fonts provided by application" setting, and it's an array:

[image]

And then you can just load the font:

```
self.label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myfont" size:14.0];
```

Keep in mind that the name in Info is the filename. The name in `fontWithName:size:` is the font name. They can be different, especially if you rename the file; that doesn't rename the font.

Fontello will tell you the code for each glyph. If it says U+E800, you'd put that in an `NSString` as `@"\ue800"`.

You'll probably create fonts that don't have every character in them (this happens with built-in fonts too, but you don't usually notice it or worry about it). You can easily mix this stuff into "normal" text like:

```
self.label.text = @"Hey! \uE800";
```

If iOS can't find a character for `H` in your font, it'll fall back to the default font. You may want more control than that, so that you can mix and match from fonts and select just the right font for each character. If you want that kind of control, see [Session 223: Using Fonts with Text Kit](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) from WWDC 2013. Some of that is iOS 7-only. With iOS 6, you may have to use `NSAttributedString` and correctly set the font for each range.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, the steps are exactly the same but the final code now looks like this:

```
self.label.text = "Hey! \u{E800}"
```